# Login form with fancybox 2.0.4

Tags: jquery, authentication, fancybox

Can you show me how to create a login form like one on old fancybox 1.3.4
demo is http://fancybox.net/blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form in the example you mentioned was made in php.

[Check this link, which include tutorials and samples about how to work with forms in php](http://myphpform.com/)

#### **UPDATE**: fancybox v2.x options are not compatible with v1.3.x. Any script from v1.3.x needs to be updated to the new options available.

For the script you mentioned you copy/pasted from v1.3.x, change the API options as follow:

this line

```
'titleShow': false,
```

should be

```
helpers : { 
 title : null
}
```

this

```
'onClosed': function() {
```

should be

```
afterClose : function(){
```

this

```
$.fancybox.resize();
```

should be

```
$.fancybox.update();
```

and this line

```
$.fancybox.showActivity();
```

should be

```
$.fancybox.showLoading();
```

then it will work

Comment: I think you diden't understand my question. There is a new version of fancybox plugin 2.0.4 but when i copy paste the code to it from http://fancybox.net/blog it doesn't work properly. the new fancybox is here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: Of course if you copy/past it won't work since options in v2.x are not compatible with v1.3.x. Check my update to see what you have to change in the same script.